# How to point strokes into the same direction?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I am trying to achieve this effect on an even bigger poster with many more strokes. I want these random strokes to point into a specific direction. There is a tool or effect that can help me with this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You have three straight rows of cross-strokes there. Is it required that the cross-strokes appear on the poster as straight rows/groups, more or less perpendicular to the (slightly randomized) direction that the cross-strokes must point? or are you just looking for a lot of little strokes that point at the center X, with some slight variation, but not arranged in individual straight rows/groups?

Answer (score 3):

Assume, you already have a bunch of parallel strokes:

[image]

Select them all and open Object->Envelope Distort->Make with Warp:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Split long straight lines that all begin from your accumulation point.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Draw a dashed stroke....

[image]

With the path selected, choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` and set the **original point**, **angle of rotation**, and **number of copies** desired, then click `OK`.....

[image]

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance`

Choose `Object > Expand`

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to delete what you don't want....

[image]

Rotate group as desired....

[image]

For added effect, you can do some perspective distorting as well...

[image]